# XML Parse ERROR : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

here shows my error

```
[Fatal Error] designations.xml:1:15: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "value".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/priyan/hr_openerp/XMLParserPro/src/com/priyan/designations.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 15; Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "value".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:251)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:300)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:205)
    at com.priyan.XmlParserMain.main(XmlParserMain.java:20)
```

here shows my code

```
public class XmlParserMain {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("/home/priyan/hr_openerp/XMLParserPro/src/com/priyan/designations.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);//ERROR COMES IN THIS LINE
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element :"+ doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    System.out.println("Designation: "+ eElement.getAttribute("OPTION"));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my xml file which i'm going to parse

```
<designations>
<OPTION value=3D777>3D Graphic Designer</OPTION>
<OPTION value=3D382>Account Executive</OPTION>
<OPTION value=3D108>Account Manager</OPTION>
<OPTION = value=3D1>Accountant</OPTION>
<OPTION = value=3D501>Accountant Inventory to Accountant = Payble
</OPTION>
<OPTION value=3D304>Accountant Payable</OPTION>
<OPTION value=3D84>Accounts Assistant</OPTION>
```

Comment: should `value=3D777` not be `value='3D777'` ?

Comment: Why is there `OPTION =value= 3D1`.. ? Is this correct..?

Comment: thanks all..issue with tag attribute
so i added '' in attributes and now seems issue is ok  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `value` attribute in the `option` tag. You need to have **quotes surrounding the value** of your id.

```
<option value='id'>XYZ</option>
```

OR

```
<option value="id">XYZ</option>
```

You can use either of the quotations. Single or double.

For reference check: [XML Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp)

Hope it helps.:)

Answer (score 1):

All the attribute values of an xml tag should be enclosed with quotes. So your Value attribute should be enclosed with quotes

Example :

```
<person sex="female">
  <firstname>Anna</firstname>
  <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</person>
```